# Name error uninitialized constant module rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, uninitialized-constant

I have a rails application in that I have modules inside `/app/adapters/UDB/` folder. The module is not loading. I have added the following in `application.rb`

`config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/app/adapters/**/*"]`

I am calling module from model file `/models/userinvite.rb`

```
   def update_cassandra
    ypusers = UDB::YpRewards.new.ypusers
    ypusers.execute("UPDATE invitation_backlog SET invitation_code = '#{invitation_code}', invitation_sent_date = #{invitation_sent_date.to_i * 1000}, invited_by = '#{invited_by}' WHERE email_address = '#{email}'")
   end
```

/app/adapters/UDB/yp_rewards.rb

```
   module UDB
   class YpRewards
     def initialize

     end
     def ypusers
        @ypusers ||= UDB::Connection.new.connection.connect('ypusers')
     end
   ...
```

Please help me solving it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with module name.

Your module name is UDB, then you can load this module by specifying its name in smallcase letters as per rails naming convention (camelcasing)

```
 config.autoload_paths += %W( #{config.root}/app/adapters/u_d_b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try including the module in your UserInvite model,

```
include UDB
```

[This is a good site to know more about the placement and usage of modules.](http://www.benfranklinlabs.com/where-to-put-rails-modules/)